# Get position of last character in Tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't want the `row` and `column`, but rather I want the actual coordinates on the screen. I need this information because I want to place a `listbox` right below where the user is typing.

Comment: How do you know that the user is at the last character? Isn't it better to get the coordinates of the insertion character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The screen coordinates of the lower right corner of the character at the text cursor can be determined by taking the bounding box of that character and adding width and height to the coordinates to get the coordinates relative to the `Text` widget and then adding the screen coordinates of the top left corner of that widget:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import Tkinter as tk


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        tk.Button(
            self, text='print coordinate', command=self.print_coordinate
        ).pack(side=tk.TOP)

    def print_coordinate(self):
        """Calculate and print the lower right screen coordinate of the
        character at the current text cursor position.
        """
        character = self.text.get(tk.INSERT) 
        x, y, width, height = self.text.bbox(tk.INSERT)
        # 
        # The line end has a width spanning the whole line until the right
        # border of the text widget but it makes more sense to view it as
        # having zero width in this context.
        # 
        screen_x = x + (0 if character == u'\n' else width) + self.winfo_rootx()
        screen_y = y + height + self.winfo_rooty()
        print(screen_x, screen_y)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    mainframe = MainFrame(root)
    mainframe.pack()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```